Mac desktop: How do I right click?
I am fully up to date with blender but unfortunately I can’t right click, to right click on a Mac desktop it’s Ctrl + click. every time I right click on the object, no small windows appear which I need in order to activate “shade smooth”. How do I fix this please?

I don't know anything about Macs, but in Blender you can get to any of the right-click menu items (including Shade smooth) from the main Object menu.

You have to configure it yourself, I think is not default for Apple mice

If you're using a trackpad, just tap it with two fingers.If you're using a Magic Mouse, then you need to go to System Preferences, then Mouse, and enable "Secondary Click".
Documentation here

Thank you so much!

Ay, no problem!  Happy Blending!
